# What do you think about Sonar's Bad practice - Finalizer only nulls fields?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, sonarqube

When you do something like below,

```
@Override
protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    ////////////////////////
    
    this.aVeryBigComponent = null;
    
    ////////////////////////

    super.finalize();
}
```

Sonar complains about

> Bad practice - Finalizer only nulls fields
>
> findbugs : FI_FINALIZER_ONLY_NULLS_FIELDS
>
> This finalizer does nothing except null out fields. This is completely pointless, and requires that the object be garbage collected, finalized, and then garbage collected again. You should just remove the finalize method.

As long as I know setting a field to null helps garbage collector destroy an object in the first run/generation. If I do not set the field to null, that object may be sent to the second generation and will wait more.

What do you think?

Comment: Sonar says: Setting a field to null does not help garbage collection. It makes it worse.

Comment: An even worse, classes with a finalizer take an extra GC cycle to be recovered. I think the good practice is *never use finalizers unless you _do_ know what you're doing*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> If I do not set the field to null, that object may be sent to the second generation and will wait more.

If you don't have a finalizer *at all* then your object will be eligible for garbage collection earlier, and its fields won't be counted as GC roots, so the other objects may be eligible for garbage collection at the same time.

Even if you *do* need a finalizer, unless that finalizer resurrects the object, the finalized object will still be eligible for garbage collection, so its fields won't keep the other objects alive.

It's very *very* rarely a good idea to write a finalizer in Java... and if it's just going to set fields to null, that's definitely a bad idea. (It will almost certainly *hurt* performance rather than help it.)

Answer (score 2):

> Objects with finalizers (those that have a non-trivial finalize()
>   method) have significant overhead compared to objects without
>   finalizers, and should be used sparingly. Finalizeable objects are
>   both slower to allocate and slower to collect. At allocation time, the
>   JVM must register any finalizeable objects with the garbage collector,
>   and (at least in the HotSpot JVM implementation) finalizeable objects
>   must follow a slower allocation path than most other objects.
>   Similarly, finalizeable objects are slower to collect, too. It takes
>   at least two garbage collection cycles (in the best case) before a
>   finalizeable object can be reclaimed, and the garbage collector has to
>   do extra work to invoke the finalizer. The result is more time spent
>   allocating and collecting objects and more pressure on the garbage
>   collector, because the memory used by unreachable finalizeable objects
>   is retained longer. Combine that with the fact that finalizers are not
>   guaranteed to run in any predictable timeframe, or even at all, and
>   you can see that there are relatively few situations for which
>   finalization is the right tool to use.
>
> If you must use finalizers, there are a few guidelines you can follow
>   that will help contain the damage. Limit the number of finalizeable
>   objects, which will minimize the number of objects that have to incur
>   the allocation and collection costs of finalization. Organize your
>   classes so that finalizeable objects hold no other data, which will
>   minimize the amount of memory tied up in finalizeable objects after
>   they become unreachable, as there can be a long delay before they are
>   actually reclaimed. In particular, beware when extending finalizeable
>   classes from standard libraries.

For complete article please refer to http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01274/index.html

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Actaully, it will do the opposite of what you suggest.

> I know setting a field to null helps garbage collector destroy an object in the first run/generation.

Using a finalizer means both objects cannot be collected until after the finalizer has been called in the finalization thread.

> If I do not set the field to null, that object may be sent to the second generation and will wait more.

If you do not use a finalizer, both objects can be cleaned up at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Sonar is correct - you don't have to set references to null for the GC to do the right thing.

"As long as I know setting a field to null helps garbage collector destroy an object in the first run/generation." - as far as I know, none of this matters.  The GC is much smarter than you.

Answer (score 0):

`finalize()` method on you instance is invoked just when your instance is about to get garbage collected.

This means, all the fields of your instance also will be garbage collected, hence there is no need of explicitly doing so.

Comment: Only true if the only reference to the field is the one in this object.

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee when, or even if the finalizer is called.
If an object goes out of scope, it is a candidate for gc. If it has a finalizer, this would be called before the object is destroyed.

It is possible for a finalizer to bring an object back into scope, (it might call some register(this) method) so maybe that's why the garbage collector would not delete the object on this pass, but wait till the next round to determine if the object is still out of scope. 
If it has no finalizer, the gc can be sure that it isn't brought back into scope, so it is safe to delete it.

Also, don't confuse setting a field to null removing a reference to that field, and the object who's finalizer you are in. These are two separate objects that can be garbage collected at different times.